# Destroy EMF Bean failed using getBeanFactory().destroyBean

Tags: java, spring, jpa

how can i force the close and the destroy of the current EntityManagerFacotry? 
The code below failed, after his execution i have many exception of entityManager is closed during the creation of new managed beans (during the injection)

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf =  (EntityManagerFactory) getWebappContext().
getBeanFactory().getBean('erpEMF');    
    emf.close();
    getWebappContext().getBeanFactory().destroyBean('erpEMF', emf);

...getBeanFactory().getBean('erpEMF') return the same object after this code !
```

How to destoy the current instance to force the instanciation of new ONE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had defined a custom scope that unfortunately doesn't clean the beans correctly.